# Inserting tabs in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

This is going to turn out to be simple, I'm sure, but I couldn't find anything on Google about this. I have a Winforms application that has a textbox. When I hit the TAB key, the cursor is jumping to the next control. What I want instead is for an actual tab (or 4 spaces) to be inserted into my textbox. What property am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should set the [`AcceptsTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) property to `true` on your `TextBox`.  This will insert an actual TAB character.

From the MSDN page:

The [`Multiline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.multiline.aspx) property must also be true to get a TAB character in the control.

If the [`AcceptsTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) property is set to true, the user must press CTRL+TAB to move the focus to the next control in the tab order.